# Java jform foreground color not showing

Tags: java, swing, background, jframe, foreground

I'm programming in Java using Netbeans.  I'm not a new programmer but new to Java and just adding components and changing some properties.

I've got a combobox I added and changed the foreground color to red.  I also changed the background color to green (just messing around, not keeping it this way).  In design view and preview design, I can see the red foreground lettering but not the green background.  After I compile, I can see the green background but not the red foreground.  Properties were all changed through the designer and initcomponents generated code hasn't been changed and clearly shows:

```
comboOne.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(102, 255, 0));
comboOne.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 0, 0));
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If you take a look at [How to Use Combo Boxes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html) (and [Writing a Custom Cell Renderer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html#renderer)), you will see that the actually rendering of the content is done by the `CellRenderer`.  Trying to modify the `foreground`/`background` colors could be ignored by the look and feel delegates

Comment: *"Java jform.."*  Stop talking like your IDE.  DYM a `JFrame`?

Comment: Thanks MadProgrammer.  i'll read up on Custom Cell Renderer.  Andrew, not sure what you're talking about.